# How to Set Echo Variable to Sed Text Change Dynamically

Tags: bash, random, awk, sed, echo

i have an echo file that output a random line from a random.txt

```
echo $var4 | sed -n $((1+$RANDOM%`wc -l random.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' '`))p random.txt
```

Everytime the echo $var4 gives a random line of the file random.txt

Now i have another file playlist.txt

Inside the file playlist i've setted

```
a=$random
b=$random
c=$random
d=$random
```

and so on...

What i want is to replace the $random on a,b,c,d with different output of the echo dynamically

I've tried with

```
sed -i s/'$random'/$echo $var4 | sed -n $((1+$RANDOM%`wc -l random.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' '`))p random.txt/ playlist.txt
```

But it doesn't work,

any suggestion?

Comment: Here's a simpler way to get a random line from a file: `shuf filename | head -1`

Comment: Yes don't do that and instead explain what it is you want to do (as opposed to how you want to do it, which is what you've currently told us) with clear sample input and expected output so we can figure out how to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you for your fast respose, what i'm trying to do is this: i have a file with 200 line suppose.. i want to put randomy those 200 lines in another playlist.txt files that are formatted like this   <video length="-1" src="mp4:" start="0"></video>
   <video length="-1" src="mp4:HERE I WANT TO PUT RANDOM LINE" start="0"></video>
   <video length="-1" src="mp4:HERE I WANT TO PUT RANDOM LINE" start="0"></video>
   <video length="-1" src="mp4:HERE I WANT TO PUT RANDOM LINE" start="0"></video>

Comment: basically i want to put random line inside other lines in another file... the file echo $var4 | sed -n $((1+$RANDOM%`wc -l random.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' '`))p random.txt generates what i want as output... but i don't know how to insert this on my file playlist.txt .. cause i want that in the file playlist.txt in every line must be a different output of the echo

Comment: @glennjackman how can i use shuf inside sed? i've tried this but no luck...  sed -i s/'$video'/'shuf random.txt | head -1'/ playlist.txt

Comment: Is "playlist.txt" just a subset of the lines in "random.txt"? If yes, the throw out everything you have and do `shuf random.txt | head -n $X > playlist.txt` where X is the number of lines you want to put into the playlist

Comment: @glennjackman i need to put many different random line of the file random.txt in the file playlist.txt in a specific position the file playlist.txt is like this <video HERE I WANT A RANDOM LINE </video>
      <video HERE I WANT ANOTHER RANDOM LINE </video>

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant information. Do not try to add it in comments which cannot be formatted.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you! Check out down in the post i've added a new answer where i explain better the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat <<'HEAD' > playlist.txt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil title="liveongroup">
<head></head>
<body>
<stream name="liveongroup"></stream>
<playlist name="default rotation" playOnStream="liveongroup" repeat="true" scheduled="2015-08-28 09:38:00">
HEAD

shuf random.txt | sed -e 's/^/<video length="-1" src="mp4:/' \
                      -e 's/$/" start="0"><\/video>/' >> playlist.txt

echo "</playlist></body></smil>" >> playlist.txt
```

Comment: Yes! It Works Man! Thank you! Awesome Solution